# C++ std::deque copy constructor issue

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, deque

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    A(int* const p) : m_P(p) {}
    A(A&& rhs)      : m_P(rhs.m_P) { rhs.m_P = nullptr; }
    A& operator=(A&& rhs) { delete m_P; m_P = rhs.m_P; rhs.m_P = nullptr; }
    ~A() { delete m_P; }

    A(A const& rhs)            = delete;
    A& operator=(A const& rhs) = delete;

    int* m_P;
};

int main()
{
#ifdef DDDEQUE
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::deque<A> > >  vd;
    vd.emplace(vd.end(), 1, std::deque<A>());
#endif // #ifdef DDDEQUE

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<A> > > vv;
    vv.emplace(vv.end(), 1, std::vector<A>());
}
```

If compiling with g++ 4.8.5, 5.2.0, 5.3.0 and `-DDDDEQUE` I get a verbose error message ending with

```
.../bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
gcc.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
      A(A const& rhs)            = delete;
```

without `-D...` compiles OK.
With VC2015, VC2012 both versions compile OK.
Does `deque` (but not `vector`) need the copy constructor for gcc?

Comment: Unrelated, you're missing a `return` value in your move-assignment operator. And fwiw, you can add clang 3.8 to the list of toolchains this compiles with even when `DDDEQUE` is defined.

Comment: This seems more a question about gcc. So perhaps `gcc` should be a tag. Btw, any difference if you use `vd.emplace(vd.end(), 1, std::move(std::deque<A>()));` instead?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be specific to libstdc++ (gcc); given the code below;

```
struct A
{
    A() {};
    A(A&&) noexcept { }
    A& operator=(A&&) noexcept  { return *this; }
    ~A() { }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    a.push_back(A{}); // or emplace(a.end()... etc.
    std::vector<std::deque<A>> b;
    b.push_back(std::deque<A>());
    std::vector<std::pair<int,A>> c;
    c.push_back(std::pair<int,A>{});
    std::vector<std::pair<int,std::deque<A>>> d;
    d.push_back(std::pair<int,std::deque<A>>{});
}
```

G++ fails to compile `b`, and `d`, clang compiles all 4 (except possibly `d` depending on the version of libc++ used) and MSVC compiles all 4 cases (using their own associated standard library; with libstdc++, clang also fails `b` and `d`).

> Does `deque` (but not `vector`) need the copy constructor for gcc?

It appears as though, yes gcc does still require the copy constructor.

---

In more formal terms; in C++03 [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) required the type used in the container to be *Copy Constructible* and *Copy Assignable*. This changed in C++11, the requirements were relaxed, albeit a complete type is generally still required - given the OP sample, your standard library still requires the copy construction and assignment.

From the linked reference;

> `T`    -   The type of the elements.
>
> `T` must meet the requirements of *CopyAssignable* and *CopyConstructible*.    (until C++11)
>
> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of *Erasable*, but many member functions impose stricter requirements. (since C++11)

Comment: "*This changed in C++11, you could look to use the language level to enable the support*", move-constructor, `emplace`, `deleted` functions, these are all C++11 features (= OP already has C++11 enabled)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki. I realise that - but his code still requires the copy constructor etc.

Comment: vector has the same relaxed requirement, I read the question as: "which operation causes deque to require copy-constructability"

Comment: [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/15pZNpCDhasuNqzQ) works well too. Isn't just GCC too strict for `deque`?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki. It appears as it is a quality of implementation issue. In particular the combination of the `pair` and `deque` - and the `deque` in particular.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I compiled with -std=c++11. And in the real code I have variadic templates and more (for g++.5.3.0), so the compiler should be OK with C++11

Comment: @Volker. I've updated the answer with something of a MCVE, it appears to be a QoI issue.

Comment: It's not `deque` being too strict; it's that a) its move constructor in GCC's implementation isn't `noexcept` and b) `deque` - like most containers - lies to `is_copy_constructible` when instantiated with a noncopyable type. This interacts badly with `vector`'s `move_if_noexcept` semantics.

Comment: @T.C. For the clang failure in this answer - (given the compiler error message), I think the rvalue is changed to an lvalue (`const&` during this construction (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/release_38/include/utility#L384); which differs from master here (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/utility#L478). I don't have access to a trunk build to check if it is correct in later builds...

Comment: Which version of clang are you using? I can't repro your error with `d` on wandbox.

Comment: @T.C. Coliru - 3.8.0 (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18b4efb22239cf43) - I can't repo on Wandbox with either the head or 3.8.0. What version of libc++ does coliru then have...? I'll need to update the post.

Comment: I've got trunk libc++.  I confirmed that it works.  Then I removed the `noexcept` from `deque`'s move constructor (which is not required by the standard), and libc++ trunk fails with attempted access to `A`'s deleted copy constructor.  Neither gcc nor VS have a `noexcept` `deque` move constructor: http://howardhinnant.github.io/container_summary.html